# HWIOAuthBundle - FOSUserBundle - Symfony 2 - Redirect to custom path after login with facebook

Tags: facebook, symfony, oauth, hwioauthbundle

Reflected the following problem after the user login with the Facebook account: that is redirected to the following route `/#_=_`

How can I redirect it to this route instead: `/` Or to more to this `/#` ?

On the client side, I use the backbone.

Comment: Did you get answer to this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect using javascript. Add following to the page.

```
<script>
    // Handle facebook callback
    if (window.location.hash && window.location.hash == '#_=_') {
        window.location.hash = '';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 9):

Taking @Prynz's idea, we can get further and create a "redirect to page user comes from" this way:

1) In your firewall, take care to remove the following lines:

```
# security.yml

# ...
logout: true
logout:
    path: /logout
    target: /
```

As we will implment the logout ourselves to avoid redirecting to the specified `target`.

2) Add @Prynz's solution to your security.yml (or config.yml depending on your implementation)

```
oauth:
    resource_owners:
        google: "/login/check-google"
        facebook: "/login/check-facebook"
        twitter: "/login/check-twitter"
        sensio_connect: "/login/check-sensio-connect"
    login_path: /login
    failure_path: /login
    default_target_path: /welcome # THIS LINE CONTRIBUTES TO THE MAGIC
    oauth_user_provider:
        service: app.oauth_user_provider
```

3) In your routing, add a new controller (here, `LoginController`) **before HWIO's imports**:

```
fuz_app_login:
    resource: "@FuzAppBundle/Controller/LoginController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

4) Create the corresponding controller:

```
<?php

namespace Fuz\AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;

class LoginController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        if ($this->getUser())
        {
            // already-logged user accessed /login
            return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer'));
        }
        else
        {
            // redirect to the login page
            return $this->forward('HWIOAuthBundle:Connect:connect');
        }
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="logout")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     */
    public function logoutAction(Request $request)
    {
        // we do a manual logout just to redirect the user to where he comes from
        $this->container->get('security.context')->setToken(null);
        return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer'));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/connect/{service}", name="connect")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     */
    public function connectAction(Request $request, $service)
    {
        // we overwrite this route to store user's referer in the session
        $this->get('session')->set('referer', $request->headers->get('referer'));
        return $this->forward('HWIOAuthBundle:Connect:redirectToService', array('service' => $service));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/welcome", name="welcome")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     */
    public function welcomeAction()
    {
        // on login success, we're redirected to this route...
        // time to use the referer we previously stored.
        $referer = $this->get('session')->get('referer');
        if (is_null($referer))
        {
            return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('home'));
        }
        return new RedirectResponse($referer);
    }

}
```

5) relax.

Comment: Thanks, happy to learn that this helps. For a more complete implementation, you can look at [this file](https://github.com/ninsuo/symfony2-quickstart/blob/master/src/Fuz/QuickStartBundle/Controller/UserController.php), [this one](https://github.com/ninsuo/symfony2-quickstart/blob/master/src/Fuz/QuickStartBundle/EventListener/LastRouteListener.php) and [that one](https://github.com/ninsuo/symfony2-quickstart/blob/master/src/Fuz/QuickStartBundle/Base/BaseController.php). Enjoy!

Comment: One thing I did differently was in the first file on line 27, inside the `else` I added `$this->get('session')->set('referer', $request->headers->get('referer'));` because my login page contains the links to my OAuth connect routes. So by setting the referer here I get the real referer, else the referer is always the login route for my OAuth users, as they always come via `/login`.

Comment: I also changed line 65 in that file to this as I was getting weird-ness `if(!strlen($referer) || preg_match("/login$/", $referer))`

Answer (score 5):

You simply add `default_target_path: /whatever/path/you/want` to the `oauth` section under the firewall setup

```
oauth:
    resource_owners:
        facebook: '/login/check-facebook'
        google: '/login/check-google'
        windows: '/login/check-windows'
        twitter: '/login/check-twitter'
    login_path: /login
    failure_path: /login
    default_target_path: /whatever/path/you/want
```

Have a look at https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/issues/89

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can redirect the users to the current page doing this way:
Add in your config.yml

```
hwi_oauth.target_path_parameter: "target_path"
```

In your view append the urls with:

```
&target_path=...
```

remember you can take the current route name with

```
app.request.get('_route')
```